# How to get job or application IDs from SparkSession?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I know how to get jobID / ApplicationID from `sparkContext`. Is there a way to get jobID / ApplicationID from `SparkSession`?

In `sparkContext`, we can

```
sc.applicationId
res0: String = app-20150224184813-11531
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The solution is to access `SparkContext` via `SparkSession`.

```
spark.sparkContext.applicationId
res0: String = app-20150224184813-11531
```

Comment: @Jacek Laskowski, what is the different between application id and session id ?

Comment: Please ask a separate question so it's visible to others. Ping me once done. Thank you.